# How to make job execute as a "flyweight" job

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to make a job of mine execute as a "flyweight" job so that it doesn't take up any executors?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do so with any job you like. Whether it will occupy regular or flyweight executor depends on the Job type implementation.

The reason is that number of executors should guarantee the maximal amount of jobs running in parallel on given slave. The job type implementor is trusted to decide whether the specific task can interfere with regular jobs or not. And if it can, it should occupy regular executor. It it ware configurable per job, every user can violate this guarantee.

You can workaround the problem configuring your job to use a job type you know does not take regular executor. Though, I have not found any that would allow it in non tedious way.